# Customize protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

Tags: html, protractor

I'm generating an HTML report using protractor-html-screenshot-reporter.
I get false/true under the Passed column but I want Passed/Failed instead.

```
Expected - Failed(in red) or Passed(in green)
Actual   - False(in red) or True(in green)
```

Code Snippet -

```
function defaultMetaDataBuilder(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities) {
                    var metaData = {
                        description: descriptions.join(' ')
                        , passed: results.passed()
                        , os: capabilities.caps_.platform
                        , browser: {
                            name: capabilities.caps_.browserName
                            , version: capabilities.caps_.version
                        }
                        , message: ''
}
```

If I replace passed: results.passed() by this code -

```
passed: results.passed() ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'.
```

I get Passed/Failed instead of True/False but Failed also comes in Green.

How should I handle this scenario. Any suggestions are always welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter how the page is rendered. Looking at source code for [protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter) I can see that the page is fully created in javascript file.

Go to this library source code to `jsonparser.js`(protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/lib/jsonparser.js) and modify `function generateHTML(data)`. Currently it looks at `data.passed` to see if this boolean is `true` or `false`. Based on that it generates color and prints this value to the column. You want to edit this line to something like this:

```
str +=  '<td class="status-col" style="color:#fff;background-color: '+ bgColor+'">' + (data.passed ? "Passed" : "Failed") + '</td>';
```

Personally if you expect to modify this page even more, I would advice you to move this code into html page instead of generating it inside javascript file.